# upgrade magento community edition to latest version

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.2.6, magento-community

Today we receive an email from Magento company pointing that customers with magento commerce 2.2.x must upgrade their product version from 2.2.x to 2.3 because there will not be supported no longer. Right now we are using the community edition for magento 2.2.6 and really don't if it's necessary, also some plugins may not work with the latest version and that means work to do.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this document [here](https://magento.com/sites/default/files/magento-open-source-software-maintenance-policy.pdf) Magento no longer offers support(bug fixes or security patches) for 2.2.x versions.

If you want to prevent any security vulnerabilities(which are fairly documented) present or upcoming, you should upgrade to the latest version.